# ActiveRecord::Base.transaction validation missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Rails 4.1.16 or 4.2.7

Lets, for example, we have

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
validate :name, presence: true 
end
```

Then in IRB we will get

```
Foo.create # => validation error
Foo.transaction{ Foo.create } # COMMIT
```

I can figure out, that there is no `raise` in transaction block, it mean, that it will be committed (on course I can use `create!`, but it does not cancel the question). But validation fails! IMHO this behaviour is not less than strange.

Can you clarify, why it was made in this way? May be I'm do not understood some specific in this case?

It will be perfect, if you know how to make `ActiveRecord` failing loudly, with no sense of !(bang) at the and of the command.

Thank you!

Comment: wrap `Foo.create` in `begin/rescue` construction inside `Foo.transaction` and handle exceptions there.

Comment: what is the issue with using ! (bang) - it gives you exactly what you need surely? It runs the validation and raises ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid which you can rescue.

Comment: The problem is, that this code should be entered by user (I'm writing the gem now), and I do not want to make this limitation for gem users if it is possible to get around it.

Comment: And there is no problem with static code, only with dynamic code.